# What happened on the away mission with Jack Crusher?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, jean-luc-picard

I know somebody asked what happened between Jack Crusher and Picard. I also read the answer which I already knew. There was an accident on the Stargazer, Picard had to choose between life or death, Picard is somehow responsible for making a choice that led to Jack Crusher's death. These sets of facts were laid out over many episodes.

Do we know the actual reason how and why Beverly Crusher's husband died? What was the away mission? What were the circumstances? What decision did Picard make?

Is there anything in the novels or anywhere else that describes the details of the away mission any more than what I've stated already?

Comment: @Lexible you missed one! I capitalized a W you missed, lol.

Comment: I've moved my answer over to the dupe question rather than having two copies of the same answer. Although this wasn't technically a dupe before, I think it's clear that they're too close for comfort.

Comment: @Richard I addressed how this is not a duplicate answer. I'm not interested in the set of facts on that question. I want to know what happened on the away mission.

Comment: @Richard It's interesting that you're the only one, at least consistently, and for awhile now that marks my posts as duplicates, too broad, etc. when clearly they're not. I asked about an away mission. As far as I can tell nobody has answered this question w/anything other than what I already stated in a few sentences. The fact that you're a moderator, have been on this site for a long time, & decided to answer my question now on an old outdated thread, never bothered to post it over there before, and shut mine down is telling. Clearly they're not the same & you've taken special interest in me

Comment: It's not strictly a duplicate in the sense that you've asked for the specific **place** where you can find out about Jack Crusher's death (which the other question didn't). It is, however worth noting that it's not the *age* of the question that makes it a dupe but the *scope* of the question (his was wider). It's also, largely a question of which question has answers that answer the dupe (again, the answer on the dupe question doesn't specifically answer yours which is why I've replicated my answer over).

Comment: FYI, not only am I a moderator but I also hold the gold tag badge for Star Trek. Even if I wasn't a mod, I'd still have the ability to close questions as dupes where I feel it's appropriate. If, however you have an issue, I'd strongly suggest you raise it on the [meta site](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/), where these things can be discussed and explained in more detail.

Comment: You can also canvass for support in chat. You may get sufficient votes to reverse my decision. I won't go against a popular vote. That said, simply saying "**this isn't a dupe**" is not sufficient to not make it a dupe :-)